# Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio: creating scripts like in mySQLWorkbench

Tags: mysql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, mysql-workbench

I just wanted to know if Microsoft's Studio has the following functionality of mySQLWorkbench:

- After inserting, updating, deleting etc. cols in mySQLWorkbench using GUI, you clik on "Apply" and a new window pops up where you have your complete query according to changes you have made.

On the other side Microsoft's Server only offers that the user generates some predefined scripts, which should be changed manually each time.

So, perhaps i missed it, i want to be sure:

Does "Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio" offer the described functionality of "mySQLWorkbench" ?

Answer (score 1):

mySQLWorkbench isn't primarily a Databse-Frontend, it's a Design- and Development IDE that could connect a Database-Server.

The Managementstudio is to manage and Maintain Servers. It#s intended to do a different Job though. But: you can do almost anything by drag and drop and by context menus you could get the resulting code to copy/paste or save it.

There is one important difference: With the Workbench you design in theory and might connect a server. With the MS SQL Management-Studio you always manipulate a real Server. That's why i've got here a Deploy Server, One Hot-Standby and a Developmentserver (Developeditions are quite cheap) for Development and Testing.

Transact SQL is something one should learn and understand as you will need it for stored procedures or trigger-programming. GUI clicking is nice to have, but at a certain point you will have to know what GUI is doing or will have to start your Editor. The Transact SQL Help is quite good. Just start!

Comment: @moller1111 sorry, i did not do any assumptions like that. As i tried to tell you there are a lot of places where you could get the Studio to create a script of the actions you just did graphically. Nevertheless they ( i know bot tools) are a bit different. You might try the Express Edition ( its for free) yourself or you might invest 40 Euros to get a Developer Edition. So my intended answer was a slight "yes, but" and i was not trying to downgrade your SQL Knowledge at all!

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Right-click on "Tables" and choose "New Table.." or right-click on an existing table and choose "Design".  Make your changes in the designer, then right-click in the top pane and choose "Generate Change Script..."